# tinymce bbcode-plugin is deleting <p> - tags

Tags: php, tinymce, bbcode

Does anybody know, which code of tinymce is responsible, that the plugin bbcode deletes all p-tags?

I have tried to find it everywhere in the tinymce- and the bbcode-plugin-code, but I can't find the right code-position...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the [development package](http://download.moxiecode.com/tinymce/tinymce_4.0.5_dev.zip) of the current version, the file `js/tinymce/plugins/bbcode/plugin.js` contains the following lines in the function `_punbb_html2bbcode`:

```
rep(/<p>/gi,"");
rep(/<\/p>/gi,"");
```

These lines are deleting the `<p>` tags.

If you want support for the `<p>` tag, you may replace the aforementioned lines with

```
rep(/<p>/gi,"[p]");
rep(/<\/p>/gi,"[/p]");
```

You then have to add the lines

```
rep(/\[p\]/gi,"<p>");
rep(/\[\/p\]/gi,"</p>");
```

to the function `_punbb_bbcode2html`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and your fast help. I made the suggested changes, but the result is, that tiny produces divs instead of p... and wehen I save, the content gets deleted :-(

Comment: It is working man! Thank you! I had to change the "rep" into "t" as in all other lines... Later i hat to add a preg_replace-line into my newssystem and everything is working now... one more question: the news are listed as a ul with li. Every news is a li... is there a problem with the <p> inside the <li>?

Comment: @user2646170: Okay. Nesting a `<p>` element into a `<li>` element should not cause problems.

Comment: one more querstion: I just found out that it is possible to create my own bbcodes within the bbcode-file! so I created a new style_format called centertext and added to the bbcode-plugin: t(/<p class=\"centertext\">/gi,"[p style=centertext]"), Everything works fine... but is it bad for security-reasons to work like that?

Comment: @user2646170: Not necessarily. It depends on what you replace and what part of the replacement can be controlled by the user.

Comment: it is all about adding styles to <p> and <span>, after he has chosen a style from the style_format-button... That is ok, isn't it?

Comment: @user2646170: Yes, it should be.

Comment: I am so sorry, but I have to ask one more question: do you know, why a <br> occurs after every enter? Your former answer works fine, because after every enter a <p>...</p> is generated. But between every <p>...</p> automatically a <br> is generated?!?! But it is not in the database... where can I delete this?

Comment: @user2646170 TinyMCE automatically starts a new line (using `<br/>`) or paragraph (using `<p></p>`) if the return key is pressed, depending on the `force_p_newlines` setting: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:force_p_newlines

Comment: Thanks a lot! Because now <p> and <br> are generated, I also added display:inline in order to "ignore" the <br>... Thanks!